# Net::SSH.start with a password supplied but it still keeps asking me for it to enter it manually

Tags: ruby, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a server via ssh providing a password but it still keeps asking me for it to enter it manually when the script is executing:

```
session = Net::SSH.start(host, "root", password: pass) do |ssh|
  result = ssh.exec!("ls -l")

end
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Can you ssh to the same host as the same user with the same password maually?

Comment: @KarenB, it doesn't matter. I don't want to be asked, instead I want an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it fail when you are not able to connect you have to add non_interactive mode on start method

> :non_interactive => set to true if your app is non interactive and
>   prefers authentication failure vs password prompt

check this code

```
session = Net::SSH.start(host, "root", password: pass,non_interactive: true ) do |ssh|
  result = ssh.exec!("ls -l")
end
```

Try to connec to with that user doing ssh by yourself, if not you have to check your ssh configuration (you may allow root user) 
check on

> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

if you have this config.

> PermitRootLogin yes

and then restart ssh daemon.

If it still , you may check your root pass.